# how to select randomly from the set of elements in a csv file in java?

Tags: java, arrays, random

```
My Csv Structure is like this : -
apple,juicy
apple,red,
apple,fruit
ball,round
ball,baseball
ball,soccer
ball,field hockey
```

how to get a random element corresponding to same element in the first column-for example for apple it randomly selects juicy and for ball it randomly selects soccer or else when the program runs next time again it gives apple for fruit and ball for round. I am sort of clueless on how to do it,

So far my code is like this -

```
 ArrayList<String> column1 = new ArrayList<String>();

        String key=keyword[0];
        for(int i=1;i<keyword.length;i++){

            if(keyword[i].equals(keyword[i-1])){
                AlternateNew.add(alternate[i-1]);
            }else{
                column1.add(keyword[i-1];
            }

            }
```

How to get the similar array set for the second column where the second array contains randomly generated element for the second column of the csv?

My output should be have two different arrays which are -
array1={apple,ball} : for the first column array 
array2={juicy,soccer} : for second column, where juicy and soccer is selected randomly selected among elements corresponding to apple element in first column and soccer respectively.

Next time when the program runs the output is -
array1={apple,ball} 
array2={red,field hockey}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pick one of the set of values that has the same first value from the file, use a map structure with a list for the values.  Like this:

```
TreeMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

When reading, add entries into the map, making sure to initialize the list for new keys, and add to the existing list for existing keys.  The first value from the file is the key.  The second is a value to insert into the ArrayList.

Once the map is filled, iterate over the map keys (using a TreeMap, they will be in alphabetical order).  On each iteration, find the size of the list, generate a random number between 0 and (size - 1), then pull out that element of the ArrayList.

I hesitate to write code for this answer because this sounds a lot like a homework problem.

Comment: This is not a homework problem. It is a real time problem.Please help me out.

Comment: I am quite new to data structure, and basically learning, I tried it the traditional way using for loop but then I got confused on how to get the arraylist for increasing number of new keys

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection interface to put the elements in a set and then you can use mapping using map collection framework